# phpStorm 7 Code completion stopped working

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I have been working with phpStorm and it had suddenly stopped showing suggestions for code completion. When i do Ctrl + space its behaving correctly by showing all the possible options in a drop down.

I have followed the below link and have did invalidate cache but still of no use.
[PhpStorm code completion doesn't show core classes/extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727557/phpstorm-code-completion-doesnt-show-core-classes-extensions)

My Setup is:
OS: Mac - 10.9.2 (Mavericks)
PHPStorm: 7.1.3

Comment: Any recently added third-party plugins?

Comment: Please show your `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in...)

Comment: I removed and re-installed the application. Now every thing looks good.

Comment: can you reproduce or recall if IDE's inner power save mode was enabled? it prevents full range of code inspections.

Comment: thanks @buzz8year, its long time and i dont use phpstorm any more.

Answer (score 13):

I just had the same problem, fixed it when I realized I mistakenly put PHPStorm in Power Save Mode. Click the little fellow on the bottom right of your PHPStorm window and switch that off

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, the Power saving mode (File > Power Saving Mode) allow you to disable the code inspection functionnality.

However sometimes the PhpStorm code analysis failed and you lost your code completion. In this case you juste have to ask for a new code analysis (File > Synchronize [CTRL+ALT+Y]) or invalid the cache and force a restart (File > Invalid cache / Restart).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Invalidating the cache did not work for me, but this did:

Enable power save mode (File > Power Save Mode), then disable it.

Answer (score 2):

If your are using a Linux distro (Ubuntu, Debian, Centos) etc, it is due to `ibus`.

Just change the Shortcut (run: `ibus-setup` and change to Super+Ctrl+Space for instance) and everything will be fine again.

Or (my favorite): uninstall `ibus` if you are not using it.
In a Debian/Ubuntu distro should be:

`sudo apt-get remove ibus`

Ctrl+Space autocompletion should be back.

Answer (score 2):

It was power saving mode for me too. It's an option at the bottom of the File menu.

Answer (score 1):

install a previous version

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/other.html

Worked for me after I tried everything.

Comment: With the Jetbrains Toolbox it's just a click on the "rollback" menu item. You need to have PhpStorm closed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a few hours this morning. After invalidation of caches, a complete reinstall, etc.. nothing worked.

I closed phpstorm and removed the .idea folder in the filesystem. I then renamed the project folder and reopened it. Autocomplete was now working!

I noticed that phpstorm then created the old project directory in the background, even though I did not open it and put a .idea folder in it.  Something is obviously corrupted here.

Answer (score 0):

" ... stopped showing suggestions for code completion".
On mac you can invoke it by fn+ctrl+space.
Going to php-storm -> Settings -> Keymap -> Set Active Changelist you can see it is associated with ^+space.
on windows ctrl+space

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure it in the Setting (Select PhpStorm → Settings on macOS or File → Settings on Windows and Linux from the main menu. Alternatively, you can press Ctrl+Alt+S to show the IDE settings)

Configure: Settings/Preferences → Editor → General → Code Completion
and enable the **"Show suggestions as you type"** option.
[image: PHPStorm - Code completion]

If you are using a different version of PHPStorm than mine and don't see this option, you can select your version in the link and get it configured.
[PHPStorm - Code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.2/auto-completing-code.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if IDE's inner power save mode enabled, - it stops the IDE from automatically performing the full range of code inspections.