# can't show PDO calsses in phpstorm

Tags: php, pdo, phpstorm

When I want to use for example:

```
$a=new PDO()
```

[phpstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) doesn't show PDO classes. Could you please tell me which plugin activates PDO in phpstorm7 or how to activate this classes.
I use [xampp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) server and active pdo dll file but does not work

Comment: you mean suggestions are not coming or any thing else.

Comment: yes don't suggestion for pdo classes

Comment: Please show a screenshot that illustrates your problem.

Comment: No warning. PDO Class not only displays

Comment: In such case I have NO CLUE at all what problem you are having there. Your English is not the best, so there is big chance that you have described your problem badly. That's why screenshot may clear lots of questions. If you cannot illustrate it then good luck fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by doing this: File > Invalidate Caches. That will do the trick!

Comment: make sure you are doing properly because it is the easiest solution for this issue.

Comment: for more info visit here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727557/phpstorm-code-completion-doesnt-show-core-classes-extensions

Answer (score 0):

To use the PDO from the global namespace did the trick for me. I needed to do that, because I defined a namespace for the php-file, in which I used the PDO-Class.

```
<?
namespace Important\Functions;
function f1()
{
    $pdo = new \PDO("odbc:somelink","user","pass");
    f2($pdo);
}

/***
 * @param \PDO $pdo If you want code-completition within the
 * function, I had to give phpstorm this hint
 */
function f2($pdo) {}
```